# How to log/track/confirm file deletions on Mac server?

Tags: sharepoint, mac, file-sharing

I have 30 or so users using a sharepoint on a Mac OS X server.

We have historically had a lot of issues with people deleting files (accidentally or otherwise) that shouldn't be deleted for various reasons.

Is there any way that I could set the server up to require a password be entered or issue a confirmation dialog before deleting a file? Further, is it possible to log file deletions to track who had deleted files and when?

I've looked into version control systems, but that may be too heavy-handed (and too expensive) for what we need.  We do have a daily back-up system in place, but my users want an extra layer of security.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized after posting that your users were using SharePoint, and not deleting files from the command line, which makes my answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can tell there is not out of the box functionality for this

generally you always get a confirm box when you want to delete a file anyway

you can set ACL's such that by default a user can't delete files or folders, and then give them a second account with does have the delete permissions but the problem is this would require remounting the share constantly and has the possible downside that they may forget they are logged in to the delete privileged share account and can still delete without password prompts then

if your concerned about delete issues then version control may be a better way to go but this brings other issues into play such as the potential for conflicts in file changes between users (something which RCS systems do combat but some do better or worse jobs at it)

Comment: I was hoping that there was some simple solution aside from version control.  For the volume of files we work with, purchasing the additional storage required for VC would be prohibitive (especially when it comes to convincing management), not to mention training all the users.  Thanks.

Comment: ahhh management and training, that used to be my biggest nightmare too, honest answer is i dont think there is a simple option to this i'm afraid

Comment: Yeah; even if I could train the users well enough to get something like CVS/SVN working well for them, I still would have first needed to convince management that it's worth the equipment and training expense.  And I'd need to get the company's Highly Paid Consultants to agree with me before the project could be approved.  Well, hopefully someone else here will be able to think of something - if not, then I'll have my work cut out for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to logging Delete events in SharePoint, there is some basic functionality included in the 'paid' version (MOSS 2007 / SharePoint Server 2010). However, that is not particularly good. You may want to look at a third party solution [such as this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/SharePoint-Audit/summary.aspx).

Disclaimer, I have worked on this product so I am obviously biased.

Comment: I should have been more clear - the "sharepoints" I'm working with aren't related to Microsoft SharePoint.  They just happen to have the same name.  Not sure why Apple decided to give them such a confusing name - makes googling for relevant information almost impossible as Microsoft SharePoint-related information dominates the results.

Comment: Sorry, the Mac OS X Server sounded a bit weird to me in combination with SharePoint, but hey, you never know what people are up to :-) The 'SharePoint' tag brought this one to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are connecting via SMB, you may be able to use the [audit VFS module](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/VFS.html#id2650662) that ships with Samba in OS X Server.